# Complex numbers and function

Tags: complex-numbers

What domain of the z-plane is represented by 
$$|z+2|+|z-2|\lt 4$$
Please give me a hint...
Can I use the formula ?
$$|z_1|+|z_2|\geqslant |z_1+z_2|$$

Comment: Think about what this means in words: the set of $z$ such that the sum of the distances from $-2$ and from $2$ are at most $4$. What sort of shape does this remind you of?

Comment: I am confused....is it ellipse?

Comment: Hint: think triangle inequality on $|2 + z|$ and $|2 - z|$.

Comment: What is the distance from $-2$ to $2$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, well, that doesn't leave many points to consider $\dots$

Comment: Take $z_1=2+z$ and $z_2=2-z$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb C$ are complex numbers and let $|z|$ denote the modulus of $z$. Then, the triangle inequality states that

$$|z_1+z_2|\le |z_1| + |z_2|$$

similarly, we have

$$|z_1-z_2|=|z_1+(-z_2)|\le|z_1| + |z_2|$$

so let $z_1=z+2, z_2=z-2$ and observe that

$$4=|z_1-z_2|=|(z+2)-(z-2)|\le |z+2| + |z-2|=|z_1| + |z_2|$$

therefore the domain is the empty set.

Comment: I understood your method...but can please explain the last line that why this became an empty set?

Comment: @AnkitaPal - This answer derived the inequality $|z+2|+|z-2|\geq4$, which contradicts your $|z+2|+|z-2|<4$, so there is no $z$ satisfying your inequality.

Comment: Ok...thank you....I understood 

Answer (score 2):

Note that the LHS of the given equation $$|z+2|+|z-2|\lt 4$$ represents the sum of the distances of the point $z$ to the two fixed points at $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$, which has to be less than 4 according to the RHS.

Given that the distance between the two fixed points $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$ is already 4, which is the minimum of the LHS, i.e

$$|z+2|+|z-2|\ge |(z+2)-(z-2)| = 4$$

Thus, the given equation represents an empty domain.